# Paragraph does not work (var_dump)

Tags: php, paragraph, var-dump

this is my first post and I am new to this community. I'm currently learning php, but facing an issue with paragraphs:

```
<?php
$name = "Erik Mustermann";
echo $name . "<br />";
echo strlen($name) . "<br />";
var_dump($name) . "<br />";
echo "Heyho" . "<br />";
var_dump($name) . "<br />";
?>
```

output:

```
Erik Mustermann
15
string(15) "Erik Mustermann" Heyho
string(15) "Erik Mustermann"
```

Why is the string "Heyho" in the same line like var_dump even I created a paragraph?

Comment: Because, `var_dump()` isn't an HTML interpreter, it just dumps code. http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php so you got back exactly what you asked PHP to do.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but why is my string displayed in the same line even I wrote "<br />"?

Comment: Hint: Take a look at your HTML source. You'll see the breaks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php --- *"As with anything that **outputs its result directly to the browser,** the output-control functions can be used to capture the output of this function, and save it in a string (for example)."*.

Comment: Because you're not writing the `<br />` string to output where you intended to. Try `var_dump($name); echo "<br />";` instead of `var_dump($name) . "<br />";` and have a look at the raw output (i.e by pressing `ctrl + u` if you're viewing the output in a web browser) to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I'm surprised this code compiles.

With the code `var_dump($name) . "<br />";` the second part `. "<br />";` is not passed to `var_dump` and so it isn't output. What you want is:

`var_dump($name . "<br />");`

`echo` is not a function but a language construct which is why it doesn't required the braces.

As a side note, `<br/>` doesn't create a new paragraph, it creates a new line.

Comment: Alright, I'm getting closer. With this method my output is: <pre>string(21) "Erik Mustermann
"</pre>